# Altering value in a class file

Tags: java

With ClassEditor I'm able to change values of constants but is it possible to alter the code where a value is being set?

Here's an example code that appears on the file:

```
this.varr[this.sval] = 11;
```

How can I edit the file so that instead of setting 11 as the value, I can set 33?

Comment: Decompile, change the value and recompile.

Comment: Stefan, it's compiled code. Tunaki, JDGui makes so many errors on the decompiled (by the thousands) source that I'm unable to recompile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to jump into reverse engineering you might want to look into BCEL(https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) or ASM (http://asm.ow2.org/)

Here's a little thing on bytecode a lot more online, http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077233/core-java/bytecode-basics.html

Basically the java will store a value in memory you need to get the bytecode and find out where memory is and store a different value instead.

Here's JBE it can be used for simple bytecode editing, http://set.ee/jbe/

Sometimes code can be protected, for example android java code is protected by proguard... Sometimes people use ZKM http://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/features.html

There are tools known as deobfuscators that try to reverse these types of protection. They are pretty good generally but commonly fail on while loops you should find these yourself if you need them.
Basically what obfuscators do is to push things from a normal position on a stack to somewhere else multiple times with goto function in bytecode... and they almost always mess up constant int values by using byte shifts...

Comment: This is interesting, thanks!

Since you seem to know a lot about the matter, do you know if it's possible to use tools like JDGui to get decompiled source without any errors? When I decompile the class files there are so many errors that I'm unable to recompile it. If I could recompile it, I wouldn't have to reverse engineer.

Comment: Edited: added bit about protection and deobers

Comment: JBE is giving me bipush errors with integers between: 128 to 256. Is there another simple bytecode editor you'd suggest?

Comment: reJ didn't have the bipush errors, but after altering one integer from 4 digit value to 3 digit value, adding the modified class file back to the .jar file I got this error: Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again. Damn, close but no cigar..

Comment: Well it sounds like at this point the class is Obfuscated. You should work out which type of tool they used and see if someone posted a de-obfuscator for that tool.

Comment: Yeah, the code is obfuscated. But I was able to change the value of a constant with ClassEditor so it's weird I can't do this. There's basically a clause like this: if (a) { val = 706 } else { val = 2706 }, and I tried to edit the code so that the if is: if (a) { val = 706 } else { val = 706 }

Comment: I also changed the value back to original, added the file to the .jar file and I'm still getting the errors. It seems the bytecode editor does something to the file that ClassEditor doesn't do.